# Overwriting values using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to conditionally overwrite some values for a given column in my DataFrame using this command

```
enq.dropna().loc[q16.apply(lambda x: x[:3].lower()) == 'oui', q16_] = 'OUI'       # q16 = enq[column_name].dropna()
```

which has the form

```
df.dropna().loc[something == something_else, column_name] = new_value
```

I don't get any error but when I check the result, I see that nothing has changed.

Thanks for reading and helping.

Comment: You're first operation, `dropna`, is already returning a copy of the dataframe. So you're not modifying the actual dataframe

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggling with that for hours

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because dropna() is a new dataframe which is a **copy** of df, you have to do it in two steps:

```
enq.dropna(inplace=True)
enq.loc[q16.apply(lambda x: x[:3].lower()) == 'oui', q16_] = 'OUI'
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to chain anything after applying some operation  `in-place`. The result is a `None`, it doesn't return the actual dataframe

Comment: Thanks for you help. Taking @yatu 's remark in consideration I tried this `enq.loc[enq.loc[:,q16_].isna(), q16_] = 'na_temp'` then this `enq.loc[q16.apply(lambda x: x[:3].lower()) == 'oui', q16_] = 'OUI'` and it worked